# Navbar layout issues (Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a client who is very picky with how their design should be and they basically want the same navbar layout as the Versace website. I know I'll probably get flak for using Wordpress instead of just hardcoding but oh well.

What I need to know is how I go from what I have to what they want? I've added screenshots of the navbar as it is and the nav bar layout they want. As for the id's of each element, I've listed them here:

- ID for Logo = `logo`
- Class for Hamburger Menu Icon = `.et_toggle_slide_menu:after`
- Class for Shopping Basket = `.et-cart-info`
- Class for Search Box = `.et-search-field`

To sum it up in writing, the menu needs to be on the left and the shopping basket and search icon need to be of the navbar to the right.

I can't add images since I don't have 10 karma but if you go on Versaces website you will see what the nav bar needs to look like.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you give the link to your development website or website? Tell us what you have tried so far to achieve this (provide the code in your question)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's a bit unclear to what you're asking; are you asking on how to create the website? If so, your question is a bit broad. Break it down to single questions per post. If its not of a design question, then this should rather go to https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: _“To sum it up in writing, the menu needs to be […]”_ - please explain what you have tried so far to achieve this. Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can add icons in menu by scrolling at top right corner in Menu and clicking on "Screen Option" and tick "css classes" also for more customization of Navbar you can try "max Mega Menu" Plugin from here https://wordpress.org/plugins/megamenu/